# Confused about Keychain Access iPhone Distribution Cetificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing

So under my Keychain Access Iphone Distribution Certificate I have one entry.

My first question is does the amount of keys under the Iphone Distribution increase as I make more apps?

Next, does XCode use this key when you are codesigning an app?

I'm a bit confused so any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: When you are talking about "Key Access" you mean Keychain Access?

Comment: Oh yes Sorry Keychain Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you upload an app you wont get an extra "entry" in keychain access.

Unless you are using Push Notifications or any other service which require Certificate Authorization you will not make use of keychain access.

Xcode use that key/certificate (The General iPhone Distribution / Developer which you installed the first time you generate a certificate) when building for a real device with development/distribution certificates.

Hope It helps.